# How do I edit a URL and not get an HTTP500 error in Python?

Tags: python, html

I am trying to make a function in Python that will take two dates, and convert them to Unix timestamp, then use those strings inside of an html string with pd.read_csv to apply date filters to the downloaded file from Yahoo Finance.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import timezone as tz
from datetime import datetime as dt

def Datetounix(d):#enter dates as [y, m d]
    p = dt(d[0], d[1], d[2])
    return(str(p.replace(tzinfo=tz.utc).timestamp()))
d1 = [2020, 4, 14]#enter dates as [y, m, d]
d2 = [2021, 4, 14]#enter dates as [y, m, d]

aaplsite = f"https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/AAPL?period1={Datetounix(d1)}&period2={Datetounix(d2)}&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true"
```

through testing I have found that the conversion function works, however when I just the fstring and apply the values in there, when I run the string through pd.read_csv I get

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

Please reach out for clarification as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The code isn't the problem.

The error is signifying that the issue is with the web server, likely due to an unexpected condition

You can see all of the error codes for HTTP servers [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Statushttps://) for future reference